# Conditionally display whole JSP page

Tags: java, jsf

I need to display the specific JSF pages depending on definite condition.
For example if user is not logged in then don't show him UserPanel.
And if anonymous user input direct URL to UserPanel, then redirect them to login page.
I think there is must be a special tag for whole page like for individual elements:
`<p:outputLabel rendered="#{customerBean.signedIn == true}">`.

Comment: You can use `c:if` from `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` or `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core` for this purpose or `ui:fragment` with `rendered` attribute which you know already.